# How do I get socket communication between Java Applet and a PHP server?

Tags: java, php, sockets, cgi

> Can I use PHP modules, such as the one found in PEAR's `Net_Socket`
>   library, to have socket communications to a client-side in-browser
>   Java Applet (presumably using `java.net.Socket`)? If so, how? Perhaps
>   an example somewhere?

The reason here being a two parter: 1) With the popularity of Java apps on mobiles devices I can make a Java program once, and it can be easily ported to a mobile app from Java applet when the time comes. and 2) cheap shared web hosting doesn't typically support custom Java servers (not even Node.js). So, I'm looking for a way to make a server for my Java apps with socket based communication.  With this in mind, there is then a less specific question (optional):

Is there any way, or a preferred way,  (say using CGI/Perl, PHP/Python) to setup socket communications between the free services found on a cheap web host and my client-side Java apps?

(for instance, say I'm trying to make a simple chat room)

NOTE: I did find this question: [How to implement communication between Java client application (Android) and PHP server application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259438/how-to-implement-communication-between-java-client-application-android-and-php?rq=1) But it doesn't apparently involve sockets. So a chat room would require the client to pole.

Comment: look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906660/java-client-and-php-server-with-sockets. Basically it suggest to use JSON over http because of PHP's capabilities. Also,just a small note for japplets, take a look at what they can and cannot do. If your user doesnt accept signed java-applets, you cant use sockets : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: @user1724140 - Interesting, but as far as I can tell, using JSON would still require the client to pole, instead of the server pushing. Also, wouldn't it still require the headers to be sent with each message? Possibly drastically increasing used bandwidth.

Comment: The major issue that your referenced question brings up; is whether or not you really need real-time communications. As chubbsondubs said is his comment to his own answer. I suppose as long as I can get the server to push data without client poling, then it would be real-time enough.

Comment: And as far as your comment about the user having to accept signed Java applets for it to work at all.  Is there a solution using WebSockets that would prevent this?

Comment: hmm ur right on the real-time issue. For the sockets of japplets I wasnt really sure but wanted you to check before you try.

Comment: Well, it appears that as  long as the Java connects to the host it came from, then using sockets should not require user approval for unsigned applets.

Comment: I've had issues in the past getting budget web hosts to let me have long running processes and/or use a specific port to use for socket connections. Some of them kill processes that run for too long. Some of them block custom ports. If you try to use 1 process per connection and do it through the webserver, you will take the server down quickly as it will consume huge resources - so you need a long running process that listens on a dedicated port.